# Abelian normal subgroups proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

If $A$ and $B$ are normal subgroups such that $G/A$ & $G/B$ are both abelian prove that $G/(A \cap B)$ is abelian.

I did it as follows

Consider the mapping $\phi : G/A \rightarrow G/B$ defined as $gA \mapsto gB$.

$\ker(\phi) = A \cap B$ by first isomorphism theorem $G/(A \cap B)$ is isomorphic to the image which is subgroup of $G/B$, so it must be abelian since the group $G/B$ is abelian.

Comment: The "map" $\phi$ is not well-defined by $gA \mapsto gB$ in general.

Comment: Hint: What is the kernel of $G \rightarrow G/A \times G/B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{amsmath}$ 
$\require{mathtools}$
 The group homomorphism 
$$ 
\begin{align}G&\rightarrow G/A \times G/ B\\
g &\mapsto (\,g A , \ g B\,)  
\end{align}
$$
has as kernel $A \cap B$, and therefore induces a monomorphism 
$$ G/ (A \cap B ) \hookrightarrow G/A \times G/B.$$
The right-hand side is abelian, by hypothesis; therefore, so is the left-hand side.

Answer (score 2):

Without an hypothesis like $A\subset B$, your map is not well defined because it is dependent of the choice of $g'$ in $gA$...

Maybe you can see that in generality, $G/H$ is abelian if and only if $H$ contains all the $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ for $x$ and $y$ in $G$. Then, with your hypothesis, this elements are in $A$ and $B$, so they are in $A\cap B$, and then, $G/(A\cap B)$ is abelian.